# Find next available date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE table with a date column. Any given date could have one or more records. My client would like the input form to default to the next date (starting from and including the current date) that doesn't yet have a record. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a query to accomplish this. Googling I've found a couple snippets, but they all use stored procedures or user defined functions which aren't available in SQL Server CE.

Is there way to do this without creating a loop in the code with multiple database calls?

Comment: "next date" as in a second, minute, hour, day, etc past the existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure that SQLCE allows all this syntax, but in T-SQL query like next would work:

```
select dateadd(d, 1, min(t1.mydatefield))
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 on datediff(d, t1.mydatefield, t2.mydatefield)=1
where t1.mydatefield>=getdate() and t2.mydatefield is null
```

Comment: Nice solution.  Just one minor problem.  DATEADD inputs are out of sequence.  Should be `dateadd(d, 1, min(t1.mydatefield))`

Comment: Thanks for noticing, fixed now.